# Libgdx Touch image interaction

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Is there a way for an image to move to a different position when the user clicks on  that image.

```
public Players() {
    deck.displayHand();

    stage = new Stage(new ScreenViewport());

    Image card1 = new Image(sprite);

card1.addListener(new InputListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {

        }
    });

}

@Override
public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {

    stage.act();
    stage.draw();

}
```

I know I have to add a listener but I'm quite confuse what to do after. The objective is for the user to touch the card image and it would move to a different location.

Comment: Should the image move everytime the same way, or what should it be doing?

Comment: Once the user touches the image it only moves once to a specific location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Move to a predefined position when you/user click on that image :

   Add an Action to that image(Actor child), 
   Let's assume predefined position is `x_pos`,`y_pos` and movement time is `t` in sec

   ```
   card1.addListener(new ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
             card1.addAction(Actions.moveTo(x_pos, y_pos,t));
       }
   });
   ```
2. Objective is to touch the card/image and it would move to a different location according to the user touch :

   ```
   card1.addListener(new DragListener(){
       @Override
       public void drag(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer) {
           card1.moveBy(x - card1.getWidth() / 2, y - card1.getHeight() / 2);
           super.drag(event, x, y, pointer);
       }
   });
   ```

---

You need to set your stage as `InputProcessor`

```
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
```

Comment: I have multiple cards and when I set the click listener for each of these cards there's a problem where when I click/touch one of the cards(eg. card1) then touch/click another card(eg. card2) the second card(card2) is sent to the back of the first selected card (card1). Is there a way for the cards to stack on top of each other (for example when the user first clicks/touches a card and then touches/clicks a second card that second card is displayed rather being sent to the back of the previous card where the user can't see the card). In general can the cards stacked on top of each other.

Answer (score 1):

`Image` is an `Actor` so you can add [Actions](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d#actions) to it.

```
card1.addListener(new ClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
        card1.addAction(Actions.moveTo(100, 100, .5f, Interpolation.circleIn));
    }
});
```